# LibGDX: How can my specific class continue to remain when I change a screen?

Tags: android, libgdx

When I change my screen to another screen I want the Hud class to still be active, so if I for an example have 60 coins on screen 1 I want the 60 coins to still remain and not restart on screen 2. 
This is what my method is on screen 2;

```
hud = new Hud5(Globals.game.batch);
```

This is how I call screen 2:

```
if(score > 60){
((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new com.mygdx.game.Level5.PlayScreen5extra());

}
```

So when I get to screen2 I want the game to continue to count from 60 and not 0.

I also got a timer runnning and I want that to follow aswell so I can't just set score to 60 on screen 2.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two ways:

create Hud object in game class and create method to get hud reference (lets say method name: getHud)

```
Hud hud = ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).getHud();
```

Create singleton object

```
public class Hud {
 private static Hud hud;
 public static Hud getHud() {
   return (hud==null)?hud=new Hud():hud;
 }

 private Hud() {}
```

Comment: Don't use static classes, specially on android you will have a bad time, just pass the java reference of the classes you wnat to the constructor of the new PlayScreen5extra class.